# How to find value?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I make this associative array with PHP.

```
$colors = ['a' => 'red', 'b' => 'green', 'c' => 'blue', 'd' => 'yellow', 'e' => 'pink'];
```

Now by using array_rand() function =>

```
$newArray = array_rand($colors, 2);
```

The Output is: [0] => a
[1] => b

This output shows me only the key of the array. But I want to see the value too.
How can I find the value of this array using array_rand()?

Comment: Loop?...........

Comment: Use the key to access the value

Comment: @nice_dev no I just want find the value like red, green... using array_rand()

Comment: @RiggsFolly How can I write the code can you give me a simple example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the keys to access the original array

```
$colors = ['a' => 'red', 'b' => 'green', 'c' => 'blue', 'd' => 'yellow', 'e' => 'pink'];
$rand_keys = array_rand($colors, 2);

foreach ($rand_keys as $key) {
    echo $colors[$key] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

```
red
blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with callback to take the randoms colors and mode `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY` to filter by keys.

```php
$colors = ['a' => 'red', 'b' => 'green', 'c' => 'blue', 'd' => 'yellow', 'e' => 'pink'];
$rand_keys = array_rand($colors, 2);

$rand = array_filter($colors, fn($colorKey) => in_array($colorKey, $rand_keys),ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$rand_values = array_values($rand);
```

**Result:**

```php
print_r($rand_keys);//Array ( [0] => b [1] => e )
print_r($rand);//Array ( [b] => green [e] => pink )
print_r($rand_values);//Array ( [0] => green [1] => pink )
```